# Looking for ideas on how to attach piece of wood to eye bolt

Tags: wood, fastener

Sorry if some terms are sounding weird, I have no idea how those things are called in English :/

Intention: I have a piece of wood (a thick stick for instance) and some eye bold sticking out of a wall. Now I would like to place said piece of wood on top of it and lock it in position.
Here are some pictures of a test:

[image: Look 1]

[image: Look 2]

The bolts are already in the wall. I cannot thread the wood through the eye and since it will be placed in our living room it should look good.

Things I've tried

- Cable ties -> look terrible but are strong
- Plastic thread -> you see the picture? :) Looks odd, not very stable, fishing threading would be more stable but visually still not great
- Metal hose clamp: Sturdy, looks still not that great but diameter of the eye bolt hole requires a smaller clamp width, small clamp width results typically in a smaller clamp diameter (too small for the wood)
- Bolt through the wood -> wood to thin to bear the weight

Hiding the fastening will be considered, but I am looking for something that looks cool

Comment: if you could tell us why you want to do this and or how the wood will be used. Also why can you not take the eye bolt out and replace it with a threaded rod with a nut and washer set up  or something else?  Having said that it occurs to me you could drill a hole in the would and use a machine bolt and nut and washer bigger then the hole in the eye bolt.   Is that the actual piece of wood you intend to use?

Answer (score 2):

I'd cut a strip of aluminium or similar sheet metal, fit it around the wooden rod and clamp it to the eye-bolt using a separate nut and bolt that pass through holes in the clamping strip and through the eye of the eye bolt.

[image]

If I didn't like to look of the bolt I'd see if I could find a large enough rivet or other type of fastener.

Answer (score 0):

Weird question but anyways... have you tried these

[image]

Or Perhaps.

[image]